# Парсинг строки при помощи регулярных выражений. Задачка на кавычки и пробелы.

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, синтаксический-анализ, powershell

Всю голову сломал себе =) из текстового файла читаются строки. В одной строке может быть "несколько параметров". Нужно строчку разделить на эти параметры.

Есть несколько условий:

- Параметры разделяются пробелами.
- Параметр может содержать пробелы, но в это случае он обязательно должен быть заключен в двойные кавычки ("").
- Никто не запрещает заключать параметры без пробелов в кавычки.

Например нужно следующую строку разбить на три.

```
D:\test "D:\test\Название папки" "D:\test\test"
```

На выходе из функции должен получить 3 строки содержащие соответственно:

```
D:\test
D:\test\Название папки
D:\test\test
```

Подскажите, как бы мне это сделать? Использование string.split() не подходит в этом случае, потому решил, что это нужно реализовывать при помощи regexp.match()...

Задача еще усложняется тем, что количество параметров может быть не ограничено. Под концом строки подразумевается \r\n

Очередной раз благодарю Вас за помощь в моей задаче

Comment: А ещё небось можно экранировать пробелы бэкслэшем?

Comment: А имплементировать обязательно при помощи регулярных выражений? Ручной сканер написать небось проще и скорее будет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
".+?"|[^ ]+
```

Только надо будет удалять кавычки у параметров, у которых они есть.

Comment: Спасибо - то что доктор прописал =)

Comment: спасибо! как раз пригодилось

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам ручной парсер (стащил [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298830/split-string-containing-command-line-parameters-into-string-in-c-sharp)):

```
public static string[] SplitArguments(string commandLine)
{
    var parmChars = commandLine.ToCharArray();
    var inSingleQuote = false;
    var inDoubleQuote = false;
    for (var index = 0; index < parmChars.Length; index++)
    {
        if (parmChars[index] == '"' && !inSingleQuote)
        {
            inDoubleQuote = !inDoubleQuote;
            parmChars[index] = '\n';
        }
        if (parmChars[index] == '\'' && !inDoubleQuote)
        {
            inSingleQuote = !inSingleQuote;
            parmChars[index] = '\n';
        }
        if (!inSingleQuote && !inDoubleQuote && parmChars[index] == ' ')
            parmChars[index] = '\n';
    }
    return (new string(parmChars)).Split(new[] {'\n'},
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

Поддерживает также и одинарные кавычки.

Можно переписать в виде генератора, будет немного поэффективнее.

Comment: Спасибо, об ручном парсинге думал, но это не красивое решение, в котором гораздо проще допустить ошибку или не досмотреть чего-то чем использовать готовые короткие решения. Как говорится - чем больше строчек кода - тем больше в нем ошибок.

@petya ответил на вопрос кратко, и то что нужно :-)

Comment: @pincher1519: подумайте о поддержке экранирования кавычек с регулярными выражениями. Она там будет сложнее. :)

Comment: @VladD, речь в первую очередь шла о полных названиях папок и файлов, а т.к. путь не может содержать некоторые служебные символы, в том числе и кавычки, то задумываться об их экранировании не стоит =)

Comment: @pincher1519: это смотря в какой файловой системе. На многих юниксах допускаются вообще любые символы в имени файла, исключая лишь `\0` и `/`.

Comment: @VladD, Опять таки, речь шла о powershell или c#, которые никсами, на сколько я знаю, не поддерживаются. Даже думаю, что через wine их проблематично запустить (если вообще возможно)

Comment: @pincher1519: под никсами есть [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap), который уже поддерживает C# 5.0.

Comment: Респект, не знал. Очень полезная информация...

Comment: @pincher1519: пожалуйста!