# Распарсить текстовый файл

Tags: c#, парсер

Есть текстовый файл куда записываются логи, его строки имеют вид

`INFO  10-04 22:09:10 DataLayer              11         Log                            - userId = 1050.`

Нужно каким-то образом разбить эти строки на элементы стрингового массива, чтобы каждый элемент этого массива содержал нужную часть данных. И выглядел примерно так:

`["Info"]["10-04 22:09:10"]["DataLayer"]["11"]["Log"]["- userId = 1050."]` где [] - это каждый элемент массива, попробовал через Split(" ") - выдало 61 элемент, с кучей элементов содержащих просто пробелы. А мне нужно именно выделить слова, все усложняется тем, что в строке много пробелов, и разбивать по пробелам не правильно, так как есть обычные фразы, где пробел идет не в качестве разделителя столбиков, а как просто речевой пробел. Как это можно решить ?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175438/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B) (cхожая задача).

Comment: Можно сначала заменить неопределённое число пробелов на спецсимвол, например \t для табуляции с помощью регулярного выражения
    s.replace(/\s+/g, "\t")
после чего уже использовать split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У метода `String.Split` есть несколько перегрузок. В частности, кроме сепаратора, он принимает количество возвращаемых строк и опцию, исключающую пустые строки.

```
string text = @"INFO  10-04 22:09:10 DataLayer              11         Log                            - userId = 1050.";
var result = text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 7, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Этот код даст почти то, что вам нужно. Только дата и время окажутся в разных элементах массива. Полагаю, это не станет проблемой для их использования.

Comment: Только еще есть "- userId = 1050."...

Comment: Если разделители гарантированно больше одного пробела, то можно использовать регулярное выражение \s{2,} и только это считать за разделители.

Comment: @Denis - Верно. При этом даже регулярка не нужна: сепаратор из двух (или более) пробелов `"  "` можно и в `String.Split` использовать.

Comment: еще раз посмотрел, если автору нужно именно как он написал, то вероятно все же split совсем не подойдет из-за даты. Проще все же регулятные выражения с группами использовать, тогда можно все перечисленное  сделать несмотря на то, что и в дате разделителем является пробел и между датой и следующим полем тоже один пробел.